# Подскажите проверенное решение для проигрывания потокового видео в браузере используя JS

Tags: javascript, html, браузер, видео, videojs

Подскажите проверенное решение для проигрывания потокового видео в браузере используя JS
Информация о видео:
Формат на входе: H264(24 bits)
Видео-декодер: H264 - Встроенный декодер FFmpeg(h264, Thread Frame)

Попробовал несколько плееров и поток m3u8 могу воспроизвести, а этот не получается.
Поток доступен и работает. На Windows с помощью PotPlayer из коробки работает.

Comment: Медиаконтейнер на входе какой?

Comment: Медиаконтейнер MPEG PS/TS